# How can I draw three cups in a row, the middle one blue, the outside ones red, and with one red cup taller than the other two cups?

Tags: image-generation, prompt-design, text-to-image

I want to use an image for [this Chinese.SE question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/54931/8099) to make my answer more vivid.  The question asks about the Chinese sentence:

> 旁边那个大点儿的杯子是我的
> To the side, the cup which is slightly bigger is mine.

I think the most natural context this would occur in is where there are three cups; something like this (but better drawn):

[image: three cups in a row, the one in the middle is blue, and the two on either side are red; one of the red cups is bigger than the other two cups]

This could arise in a conversation such as:  A: Is the blue cup yours?  B: No, to the side, the cup which is slightly bigger is mine.

So...

**Question**: How can I draw three cups in a row, the middle one blue, the outside ones red, and with one red cup taller than the other two cups?

I used the prompt:

> three cups in a row, the one in the middle is blue, and the two on either side are red; one of the red cups is bigger than the other two cups

at [pollinations.ai](https://pollinations.ai/):

> [image: pollinations.ai: the three cups are the same height; the one on the left is mostly light blue]

at [craiyon.com](https://www.craiyon.com/):

> [image: craiyon.com: the cups are not in a row, and the cups on the outside have the same size and different colors]

at [hotpot.ai](https://hotpot.ai/art-generator):

> [image: hotpot.ai: there are four teacups on a table in a circle; one of the cups is smaller]

at [freeimagegenerator.com](https://freeimagegenerator.com):

> [image: three cups in a row, the middle one is blue, the left one is red and blue, and the right one is red and larger (although slightly deformed)---not a bad example]

at [fotor.com](https://www.fotor.com/features/ai-image-generator/):

> [image: three cups of the same size, the left one is red, and the two on the right are blue]

at [deepai.org](https://deepai.org/machine-learning-model/cute-creature-generator):

> [image: two teacups; one red, one blue, of the same size, both with red saucers; they contain some kind of fur-like substance]

at [Stable diffusion web](https://stablediffusionweb.com/#demo):

> [image: three cups in a row, the one on the right is slightly bigger]

at [opendream.ai](https://opendream.ai/create):

> [image: five cups, three of which are in a row, with the middle cup blue and the outside ones red]

at [dezgo.com](https://dezgo.com/):

> [image: four containers (that don't look like cups) in a row, all but the one on the right is red; the leftmost and rightmost containers are taller]

at [nightcafe.studio](https://creator.nightcafe.studio/)

> [image: three red cups in a row of equal size]

at [runwayml.com](https://app.runwayml.com):

> [image: a white cup next to a half-off-screen red cup]

at [simplified.com](https://app.simplified.com/tools/text-to-image/results):

> [image: three cups of the same size in a row; the first two are blue with red inside, the rightmost cup is red]

at [openart.ai](https://openart.ai/create):

> [image: three red-and-blue-colored goblets of equal size]

At [replicate.com img2img](https://replicate.com/stability-ai/stable-diffusion-img2img) (using the above image and prompt as input):

> [image: a blurry mess of three barely identifiable objects]

I asked [GPT-4](https://poe.com/GPT-4) to make me Tikz code:

> Can you draw in Tikz: three cups in a row, the one in the middle is blue, and the two on either side are red; one of the red cups is bigger than the other two cups?

but it simplified the cups to ellipses:

> [image: three ellipses; the middle one is blue and the two on the outside are red; the one on the right is slightly larger.]

None of these are ideal; freeimagegenerator.com or Stable Diffusion web is the closest.

Hopefully I can get a better prompt or some alternative software suggestion for this task (while I'm not going to pay money for it, I'd still be interested in knowing what's out there).

Comment: Is using img2img ok?

Comment: (I realize I misinterpreted your comment.)  I tried a img2img method ([edit]ed in above); it's terrible.  Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I saw a demo sometime ago on Hugging Face that was aimed just at this - Stable Diffusion with positioning capabilities for entities. Can't remember the name of the sample.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones replicate.com seems to have a very low amount of steps. So you're seeing a lot more 'diffusion' than 'stable'. I wouldn't throw the baby out with the bathwater here.

Comment: Absolutely I may be using it wrong.  I just used the default settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, text-to-image generation starts denoising from random latent noise. If you instead start denoising (with a lower strength) from an existing image, you can use it to predetermine broad structures/colours in the image.

Below I use the [Stable Diffusion 1.5](https://huggingface.co/runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5/tree/main) model through [ComfyUI](https://github.com/comfyanonymous/ComfyUI) - these are FOSS and available for free. Many other frontends will also support img2img, such as Automatic1111 which has a dedicated tab for it.

ComfyUI workflow below, showing loading in (and VAE encoding) a basic sketch image where for regular text-to-image generation you'd have latent noise, and also adjusting "denoise" from 1.0 to 0.75:

[image: ComfyUI workflow]

Initial sketch:

[image: Solid-colour sketch of 3 cups]

Result:

[image: ComfyUI workflow]
(image contains ComfyUI workflow graph metadata - can be downloaded and dragged into the UI)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out one way of doing it.  I created this image at [nightcafe.studio](https://creator.nightcafe.studio/) (as per the question):

> [image: three red cups in a row of equal size]

I then manually edited the image using Krita (a drawing package), changing the hue of the middle cup, and enlarging the cup on the right:

> [image: an edited version the above image; it has three cups with the given properties; the background shadows and colors are wrong]

and then I removed the background using [removal.ai](https://removal.ai/upload):

> [image: a backgroundless image with three cups with the given properties]

I added a background in with [mokker.ai](https://app.mokker.ai):

> [image: the three cups with added golden stems resting on a bench]

Answer (score 1):

I got pretty close using [88stacks](https://88stacks.com)'s prompt generator that allows you to submit multiple variations. The problem was it added too many other cups!

[image]

Here you can see all the other variations I generated
https://88stacks.com/c/cups_test_v0

Comment: But the cups look like they're all the same size (?).